# Java for loop only storing last value

Tags: java, android-studio, for-loop

I have a `for` loop in `java` android and it runs perfectly but it only stores to the last item in the list it is looping through. Should I make `user_id` and `lesson_id` a list? I don't know where to go from here but here is what I have done. The logic works fine but it only saves one item from the lists in both variables.

Android Studio Code:

```
// loop to add every user and lesson selected to watch
String user_id = null;
int lesson_id = 0;

for (int i = 0; i<attendees.size(); i++){
    for (int j = 0; j<lesson_iDs.size(); j++){
         user_id = attendees.get(i);
         lesson_id = lesson_iDs.get(j);
    }
}
// get the date for the classWatch
Calendar localCalendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());
Date currentTime = localCalendar.getTime();

// to show in patient activity (sends to SQLite)
watch = new Watch(currentTime, user_id, lesson_id);
```

Comment: you code it to only store the last value ... if you want to store them all, you could indeed use lists  and set add.(X); instead of = ..

Comment: What is your goal? If you want to save every id then, yes, you should use some sort of collection. Currently you are only overwriting `user_id` and `lesson_id`

Comment: Okay thank you. I guess a list is the way to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time those loops run, the current values of attendees.get(i) and lesson_iDs.get(j) are stored in your two variables (user_id, lesson_id) removing the last stored value. If you want to keep all the values of the attendees and lesson_id lists, user_id and lesson_id must be lists and in the loop you have to add to them the current values of attendees.get(i) and lesson_iDs.get(j).

```
List<String> user_ids = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> lesson_ids = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i<attendees.size(); i++){
    for (int j = 0; j<lesson_iDs.size(); j++){
         user_ids.add(attendees.get(i));
         lesson_ids.add(lesson_iDs.get(j));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is normal ?
If you use user_id and lesson_id outside of the loop, you use the last values.
Don't you want to do something like :

```
// loop to add every user and lesson selected to watch
String user_id = null;
int lesson_id = 0;
// get the date for the classWatch
Calendar localCalendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());
Date currentTime = localCalendar.getTime();

for (int i = 0; i<attendees.size(); i++){
    for (int j = 0; j<lesson_iDs.size(); j++){
         user_id = attendees.get(i);
         lesson_id = lesson_iDs.get(j);
         // to show in patient activity (sends to SQLite)
         watch = new Watch(currentTime, user_id, lesson_id);
         // Do something with watch...
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is what I was looking for because the `// do something with watch` was outside the loop

Comment: This creates another problem similar to the original one, i.e. that it overwrites `watch` in each iteration and hence stores only the last `Watch` instance, even though `Watch` instances has been created for every `user_id`+`lesson_id` combo